# MediaWiki programmatically update user-groups

Tags: php, mediawiki

Is there any way to programmatically update group of specific user (in contrast to manual proceeding via Special:UserRights)?

Initial situation:
1. The requirement to use my MediaWiki is, that particular mediawiki user is in one of two Active Directory groups (Domain-MediaWiki_ReadOnly resp. Domain-MediaWiki_ReadWrite).

2. MediaWiki user authenticates against Active Directory successfully - works topically.
3. Getting programmatically the AD group, where User is in (via LdapAutoAuthentication.php) - works topically.
4. Creating two new user groups in MediaWiki by manipulating LocalSettings.php - works topically:

   $wgGroupPermissions['ReadOnly']['read'] = true;

   $wgGroupPermissions['ReadOnly']['edit'] = false;

   $wgGroupPermissions['ReadWrite']['read'] = true;

   $wgGroupPermissions['ReadWrite']['edit'] = true;
5. But now, how to programmatically map user, which is in AD group

   - 'Domain-MediaWiki_ReadOnly' to MediaWiki group 'ReadOnly'
   - 'Domain-MediaWiki_ReadWrite' to MediaWiki group 'ReadWrite'

   via bypassing 'Special:UserRights' (to add specific user to relevant MediaWiki group manually) ?

Does anyone of you guys have any idea(s)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having problems parsing your questions, but I'll try.
* If members of group A need to be the same as members of the group B, it probably means that you're doing something wrong: just assign permissions of group B to the group A.
* If group A is external to MediaWiki, you can't get MediaWiki to do something about it.

Assuming your question makes sense, the solution is $wgAutopromote. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAutopromote
So, for instance,

```
$wgAutopromote = array(
    'ReadOnly' => array(
    '&',
    array( APCOND_AGE, 60 ),
    array( APCOND_INGROUPS, 'Domain-MediaWiki_ReadOnly' ),
  ),
);
```